# Error NU1202 Package is not compatible framework, when it actually is

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2022, nuget-package

## NU1202 Package errors

I have two custom nuget packages (PackageABC and PackageXYZ), both support multi-targeting. Using this:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net7.0;net8.0;</TargetFrameworks>
```

PackageXYZ makes use of PackageABC as a PackageReference.

Recently I started getting "Error NU1202 Package PackageABC 1.0.5 is not compatible netX.X", I am **not** receiving any errors about package downgrades, or any other nuget errors. Just this one.

This is the project xml for ProjectABC:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net7.0;net8.0;</TargetFrameworks>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
        <Version>1.0.5</Version>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.1.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="8.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0' Or '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0' ">
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.15" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.15" />
        <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="7.0.11" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0' ">
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="8.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

#### The errors I am receiving when compiling PackageXYZ:

- Error NU1202  Package PackageABC 1.0.5 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package PackageABC 1.0.5 supports:

  - net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
  - net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)
  - net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
- Error NU1202  Package PackageABC 1.0.5 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package PackageABC 1.0.5 supports:

  - net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
  - net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)
  - net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
- Error NU1202  Package PackageABC 1.0.5 is not compatible with net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Package PackageABC 1.0.5 supports:

  - net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
  - net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)
  - net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)

#### The question:

What is causing the compiler to say that it does not support a framework, when it clearly does? Is there any way I can figure out what is causing this? The errors are very confusing to me, as in one part it says it does not support the framework, then in the next part of the error states that it does support the framework.

#### Here is a screenshot of the errors I am receiving:[image: compile errors]

The first three errors are because PackageXYZ fails to compile

EDIT: What is even more odd, is that I JUST compile PackageXYZ alone, it succeeds, however, when I add the PackageXYZ.Tests into the compilation the above failure occurs.

Comment: It looks like a bug in NuGet. On occasion I see other people report the same issue, but nobody has given us a sample where we can reproduce the error ourselves, in order to debug. If you can share a reproduction, please report it to github.com/nuget/home. You can report with VS's report a problem if you want to share files with Microsoft only, not publicly. Since NuGet is OSS, you can clone github.com/nuget/nuget.client and debug yourself if you can't share a minimal repro. Our tests dont reproduce the problem, so we need someone with a repro to help.

Comment: @zivkan I probably won't be able to recreate this with a minimal repro. It is beyond bizarre. However, I am open to debugging the nuge.exe. Are there any instructions on how to do so from another VS instance? It is not like I can attach to an existing process.

Comment: nuget.exe is a console app, so set `src\NuGet.Clients\NuGet.CommandLine` to the project to debug, go to project properties, set the debugging args to `restore path\to\your.sln`, then press F5. NU1202 is raised in `CompatibilityChecker.cs`, so put a breakpoint there and have a look around.

Comment: @zivkan TYVM, I will get right on it.

Comment: @zivkan, when I try to debug the app i get this error: 

error MSB4062: The "NuGet.Build.Tasks.WarnForInvalidProjectsTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\src\NuGet.Client\artifacts\NuGet.CommandLine\bin\Debug\net472\NuGet.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Build.Tasks, Version=6.10.0.32767, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A) Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies...

Comment: You might be hitting this: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/13144   If running `run.ps1 -skipunittest` doesn't fix the strong naming issue, try commenting out everything in `build/sign.targets`. I expect you wont be able to debug our VS extension, but I think the command line tools should be fine.

Comment: @zivkan Sorry, I cannot find a run.ps1 in the repo. https://github.com/search?q=repo%3ANuGet%2FNuGet.Client%20%20run.ps1&type=code 
--
I tried commenting out all of the file sign.targets, but that only caused build errors, not runtime errors. Then I tried commenting out parts of the file with no success.

Comment: @zivkan, if you are willing, we can do a zoom / google meet and debug it if you want.

Comment: @zivkan If you agree, I can start a chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ for us, where we can set up the zoom meeting.

Comment: @zivkan, So I am finally able to debug, and I have found the issue, but I am unsure of the fix or the why.

Comment: I'm on vacation, so not checking here regularly. Anyway, if you filie a bug report on github.com/nuget/home with as much specific info as you can, someone might be able to figure it out. As for debugging, debug the same code on a different project where you don't have the problem, and you can see how the code is "supposed to" work. Also, something you can try is to remove all package referenecs to private packages, and if the problem still exists, delete all code files, and share that as a reproduction of the bug. That way we can debug, and you don't need to do it yourself.

Comment: I have posted steps to repro this to the Nuget team, as well as the work around I figured out here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/13209